# Listening for connections with socket.io not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm using this code for my backend:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const io = socketIo(http);

io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("New client connected");
  socket.on("disconnect", () => console.log("Client disconnected"));
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

When I run it, it outputs the message confirming it is listening. However, on a connection it does not send any messages to the console. I'm trying to listen for connections to a React app. I have tried using other code snippets for the connection function that also claim to work as I expected, however none that I have tried have worked, including the code in the official tutorial for socket.io.
Please can anyone help?

Comment: Show the React code used to connect to this server

Comment: @zS1L3NT Sorry, I didn't know you had to connect to the server. I thought it listened for all connections to that port.

Comment: Connections meaning socket connections or http connections?

Comment: http connections

Comment: You don't need http.createServer while using express. Express handles that for you

Comment: I can post an answer to show how to make http connections to the server like GET, POST, UPDATE. Would you like that?

Comment: @zS1L3NT yes please, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const PORT = 5000

// Get to http://localhost:5000
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  // Send back some data to the client
  response.send("Hello world")
})

// Post to http://localhost:5000/getRandom
app.post("/getRandom", (req, res) => {
  res.send(Math.random())
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on PORT ${PORT}`))
```

Instead of calling the parameters `request` and `response`, people use the short form of `req` and `res`

Now start this script and go to `http://localhost:5000` and you will see "Hello world" in the HTML body. That's express, simple yet powerful :)

Comment: I get a ReferenceError when running this with node, it doesn't recognise res for some reason